# Error while building drivers on Raspberry Pi 3 board

Tags: linux, compiler-errors, linux-kernel, arm, raspberry-pi3

I am using Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Rev 1.2 with kernel 4.4.50-v7+ & facing issue while building drivers. Please find below error that I am facing

```
make[1]: *** /lib/modules/4.4.50-v7+/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
Makefile:149: recipe for target 'build_driver' failed
make: *** [build_driver] Error 2
```

Can someone help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Your first line mentions why you are getting the error

> make[1]: *** /lib/modules/4.4.50-v7+/build: No such file or directory.

It seems that the path `/lib/modules/4.4.50-v7+/build` does not exist. This may be because you have not installed kernel headers for the kernel for which you are building the driver. You can also change the Makefile of your driver to point it to the linux kernel source directory for which you are building the driver.

Comment: In have installed kernel headers but now getting different error like "Could not insert module, invalid module format" . Also when I am doing dmesg then getting message like "acexusb.ko:disagrees about version of symbol module_layout"

Comment: `Could not insert module, invalid module format` - This can be because of difference in the architecture for which you have build the kernel and the target board in which you are inserting the kernel. Besides, the kernel version magic should match with that of the kernel module.